# Rails: automatically do not render html element when in mobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm developing a responsive Rails site, I use something like `hidden-xs`(from `Twitter Bootstrap`), to hide some content when user using a mobile device.

However it still generate traffic, and make the page load slower. So I end up with a helper `<% if mobile? %>` to determine whether to generate it or not.

I think adding both `hidden-xs` and `<% if mobile? %>` is quite repetative, and wondering if it is possible that when add a `hidden-xs` css class, I can make Rails do not render the content at all? so make the webpage load a bit faster?

Additional question: Is it a good practice to use `<% if mobile? %>` to trim the content in Rails view? Because I feel there maybe too much `logic` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) gem. It should help to detect requests from mobile devices.

About better place. Look at [Variants](http://codemy.net/posts/rails-4-1-variants) functionality from Rails 4. I think it should help to split your markup on two parts: mobile and desktop.